# Extra line on beginning of output

Tags: c++, io, deque

I am supposed to write a very little program analogical to Unix `tail` function, I'm using `std::deque` to store the lines I read by `std::getline` from supplied file. Pushing in the front, popping from the back.

My problem is, that when I try to print more lines then there are in file, it outputs 1 extra blank line at the begining of output. Here is the source code, `TParams` is `struct` with `int lncount` where number of lines requested is stored, and some other at the moment unimportant stuff...

```
using namespace std;

deque<string> dq;
int counter = 0;

for(string line; ! (*infile).eof(); getline(*infile, line)){
    dq.push_front(line);

    // not needed lines dropped immediately
    if(counter++ >= TParams.lncount)
        dq.pop_back();
}

int iter = (TParams.lncount > dq.size()) ?
           (dq.size() - 1) : (TParams.lncount - 1);

assert(iter < dq.size());

for(iter; iter >= 0; iter--)
    cout << dq[iter] << endl;
```

There is some more code regarding `-n +num` parameter, but it is inside conditions and does not affect this case.

I found out, that there actually is zero length string stored in `dq.back()` but I have absolutely no idea where it comes from, as it should be the one read from beginning of file,   but there is normal line of text.

Comment: does all lines you expect are displayed or the empty line replaces an existing line in the file ?

Comment: yes there was everything I expected, plus the extraline, James Kanze found the problem, thank you for comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your read loop is wrong.  First, the value `(*infile).eof()` isn't
really specified; if you have an empty file, it could still return
`false`.  And secondly, you're not reading a line before entering the 
loop to begin with.  The classic way to write a loop like this would be:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( *infile, line ) ) {
    //  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am kind of new to C++ and I didn't quite understand the return value of `std::getiline`... And I was a little worried about the for loop before, but for the other options it worked fine so I didn't pay attention to it... Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You check for `eof` (which is probably the wrong check) *before* you read from the stream. So the final will read a blank and then set EOF in the stream, but it's too late because you already added that extra line to your `deque`.

Comment: The check for `eof` is surely wrong, but he's already off by one the first time he enters the loop, because he hasn't done a `getline`.